# Use closures in match arms

Tags: php, match, php-8

When I run the following code with `condition_2` being the match result the content of `$foo` is a closure instance, but I want the result that should be returned by that closure. How do you do this? `condition_1` is working as expected.

```
$foo = match ($conditions) {
    'condition_1' => 'some text',
    'condition_2' => function () {
        $result = '';
        // crazy programming
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just wrap the closure in [`call_user_func`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func):

```php
$conditions = 'condition_2';
$foo = match ($conditions) {
    'condition_1' => 'some text',
    'condition_2' => call_user_func(function () {
        $result = 'crazy';
        // crazy programming
        return $result;
    })
};
var_dump($foo);
```

This code will result in the output of `string(5) "crazy"`.

Alternatively, you could store your closure in a variable and just call it:

```php
$myCallback = function () {
    $result = 'crazy';
    // crazy programming
    return $result;
};
$conditions = 'condition_2';
$foo = match ($conditions) {
    'condition_1' => 'some text',
    'condition_2' => $myCallback()
};
```

There is a third way of going about this, where you could immediately call the closure if you add additional sets of parentheses (a tip of the hat to IMSoP for pointing it out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67450250/use-closures-in-match-arms/67450415#comment119249713_67450415)):

```php
'condition_2' => (function () {
    $result = 'crazy';
    // crazy programming
    return $result;
})()
```

The first set wraps the closure and allows it to be interpreted `(...closure definition...)` and the second one is an empty set denoting a call of the function: `wrapper -->(...closure definition...)()<-- call`. Maybe slightly less readable, but eliminates any middlemen (an intermediary variable or a call to another function).

Comment: Live test for the [first solution](https://3v4l.org/XSTgN) and the [alternative one](https://3v4l.org/P5GhC).

Comment: You can actually execute the closure directly without either call_user_func or an intermediate variable, but you do end up with quite a lot of different brackets: https://3v4l.org/gWS2j